# Integrating blueimp-gallery with ruby on rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to integrate `blueimp-gallery` to my `rails 4` application but when I try to display the caroussel i got this error :

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

at this line of code:

```
 style[transform.name] = 'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)' +
            (transform.translateZ ? ' translateZ(0)' : '');
```

from the blueimp-gallery.js file

This is how I configure `blueimp-gallery`

```
gem 'blueimp-gallery'
```

in application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require angular
//=require angular-route
//= require angular-animate
//= require angular-resource
//= require blueimp-gallery-all
//= require_tree .
```

in application.css.sass

```
/*
*= require rails_bootstrap_forms
*= require blueimp-gallery-all
*= require_tree .
*= require_self
*/

  @import "bootstrap-sprockets"
  @import "bootstrap"
  @import font-awesome
```

Is there anything that I am doing wrong??

Answer (score 0):

That is a JavaScript error. You can do some detective work working backwards from the error. Set breakpoints and see where something didn't get assigned properly. Here is where transform should have been defined:  https://github.com/Phifo/blueimp-gallery/blob/6d4014a5398b53f2fc854b6566ed53947b678714/vendor/assets/javascripts/blueimp-gallery.js#L224